# Rails: Upadating only a certain field using javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am writing an web application which runs on iPads in taxis. Now i want every device to call the server every X minutes and say "i am still alive".

For that reason i have a 'latest_activity' field which i would like to update with rails' Time.now

What's the best way to do this? I was thinking about sending a GET to "/app?update_id=52" and then rails would look for params[:update_id] and update the field *but this feels so dirty* and i think there has to be a better way to do this.

**Updated with solution below**

Answer (score 0):

I would `PUT` to the `update` action in the controller for whatever has the `latest_activity` field. So say the field is on `Client`, I would use RESTful style routes like so:

```
# routes.rb
resources :clients
```

And then use the endpoint:

```
PUT /clients/52
```

And of course then `ClientsController` gets an `update` method which sets the field to `Time.now` as you already mentioned.

Backbone supports this type of url scheme natively/easily. You have a `Client` model on the frontend, you simply do:

```
someClient.set( { latest_activity: new Date() } );
someClient.save();
```

Although that sort of says to me that you might just let the frontend generate the timestamp rather than doing it in rails.. otherwise you are really just sending a fake value (either a real date that wont be used or just, say, `1` and then 'notice' that on the backend). If you send a real timestamp you can just do:

```
# app/controllers/clients_controller.rb
def update
  c = Client.find( params[:id] )
  c.latest_activity = params[:latest_activity]
  c.save
  render :json => { :ok => true }
end
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the problem with sending a client generated timestamp is that the client may have a different timezone. That's why i want to generate the timestamp server side. I've posted my solution if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I've taken a slightly different path. Now i've added a *ping* method to my devices_controller

```
def ping
  if params[:id]
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    @device.latest_activity = Time.now
    @device.save()
  end
  respond_with(@device)
end
```

And added a member to the Devices resource like so

```
resources :devices do
  # Device Ping ('/api/v1/devices/#{id}/ping')
  put 'ping', :on => :member
end
```

Now i am just sending a PUT request to /api/v1/devices/ID/ping, from Backbone.js in my case, like so

```
ping: ->
  if localStorage.device_id?
    setInterval =>
      $.ajax
        type: "PUT"
        url: "/api/v1/devices/#{localStorage.device_id}/ping"
    , 1000 * 60 * 15 # every 15 Minutes
```